# Loading a large unsigned int primary key via hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

I know that java does not have "unsigned Integer" type so to map a MySQL unsigned Integer I have an option of using Long. But the problem with Long is that I can't use it for loading entities where the Id is larger than Integer's range. e.g.

```
session.get(User.class, 4294967295L))
```

Because the value is out of range for an Integer which is the primary key of User table in MySQL. 
And the above statement throws  org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: expecting class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long. Which seems logical.

So the problem is how do I map a legacy database with unsigned int into hibernate and still use session.get for values larger than 2,14,74,83,648 (2 exp 31)

Comment: Though I can do session.createQuery("from User where id = 4294967295") but that would bypass the second level cache. So want to use session.get and .load only.

Comment: You probably get a TypeMismatchedException because the ID property of User is of type int or Integer, not because of the type of the column in the database table. The ID property should also be defined as Long, of course.

Comment: Thanks JB, that was the issue, such a silly mistake :-(